# How do I Send HTML Emails via Rules?

Tags: rules, emails

The Rules module provides a value field for the "send mail" action. Since I also have the PHP filter module, I have the ability to add PHP code there. I want to add HTML formatting to my email. Is there a more "correct/Drupal way" of sending HTML based emails via rules other than pasting my code there?

The [pet](http://drupal.org/project/pet) module looks like a decent candidate, but has low-ish usage numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mimemail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) or [HTMLMail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) both look like they support Rules.